# How to continue the numerical progression $1, \frac34, \frac34, \ldots$ (without simply repeating $\frac34$)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, geometry

I found a geometrical relationship in an old diagram that corresponds to this:

$$\ 1, \frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}, \ldots$$

[image]**Enclosed is simplified sketch I drew to give some meaning to what I'm referring to. With in it, 1x=100.; the horizontal values are the important ones. (The sketch shows you where the design is cut off in the image I have.)**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
The numbers should shrink as the sequence goes on, not necessarily after every iteration but in general. The next number can be no bigger than the last. Also, no negative numbers.

I know the (now dead) inventor's son; so, I know that the invention follows some sequence.

I would be interested to know if anyone has any idea of what geometric or other progression(s) this belongs to? Obviously, there are likely lots; so, it would be good to start out with simple ones.

**Note.** I mean something other than the obvious
$$\ 1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \ldots$$

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe the $n$th term is $(3/4)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$?

Comment: I mean something other than the obvious: $$\ 1, \frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},.....$$

Comment: Only three terms doesn't give much to go on; there aren't just "lots" of possibilities, there are *infinitely many*, of which I suspect *almost-none* will fit the geometry of your diagram. Please provide that diagram, and explain how you derived your sequence from it. From this, we might be able to determine an appropriate pattern. ... In any case, the fact that two terms are equal but not all three tells us that the sequence is neither an arithmetic nor geometric progression.

Comment: $a_i=\prod_{x=1}^ {i} \frac{x+2}{4} , \ \ i \geq 0$

Comment: This question is like "Tell me the word that begins with $IMM$."

Comment: I'll add to the comment of @Blue that I think it is *necessary* for your question that you explain the old diagram, otherwise this question is in danger of being closed as too broad and too unclear.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some context. And I just realized it, the numbers should almost certainly get smaller as it goes onward.

Comment: Lee, the diagram depicted a figure that tapers in the way that my numbers would suggest. But part of it is gone.

Comment: Part of it is gone? So that makes us, what, numeroarchaeologists? You might at least post the parts that aren't gone.

Comment: LOL. I hope it's not that bad, the thing is, for other reasons, I'm sure it follows some sequence.

Comment: I posted an image, the image is my simplification of the sketch, which should give a good idea of what I'm talking about. You can see where it cuts off...

Comment: BTW, sorry to all for any issues caused by my poor formulation of the question in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, your diagram alone isn't terribly helpful. Where's the "$1$"? Where's the "$3/4$"? Where's the *other* "$3/4$"? Where would the next term even fit into the figure? (If we have to chop-off the right-hand end of the $33.333$-wide and $12.50$-tall trapezoid to make room for the next term, will that change the value of, say, the second "$3/4$" term?)

Comment: 1=100. Thank you!

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: If $1=100$, then doesn't $3/4=75$? Where's the $75$? and the *other* $75$? And, again, where do later terms *fit*?

Comment: To add more info, 1x=100, 2x=100*(1/3), 3x=100*(1/3)... The parts that are dimensioned, the horizontal ones, are the ones at issue. 

The thing is meant to have electrons sent through it and the son of the (now dead inventor) told me it follows some sequence.  

Thank you!

Comment: Total stupidity on my part, I meant to type 3/4. Extremely sorry!!

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: Please add your explanation (such as it is) to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked, especially this far down. ... As for myself, I can make no sense of what you're trying to convey, so I'll leave this to others. Good luck to you!

Comment: I may actually delete this or ask you or someone else to close it, and then post a better formulated version.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: Deleting a question that has received answers is inconsiderate to the answerers who took time to compose responses, so don't do that. :) I'll vote to close.

Comment: Thank you. You're very right.

Comment: Commendable persistence in search for the one correct and true answer! (I enjoyed reading the discussion,in particular your comment to the answer by @Eureka, saying "But what you posted is still beautiful!" :) Here: (a) $\frac22,\frac34,\frac34,\frac48,\frac48,\frac48,\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},...$; ie.$\frac{n+1}{2^n}$ repeats $n$ times for $n\ge1$, or (b) $\frac22,\frac34,\frac34,\frac48,\frac48,\frac48,\frac48,\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},\frac5{16},...$; $\frac{n+1}{2^n}$ repeats $2^{n-1}$ times. I like option (a) better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment:

$$a_i=\prod_\limits{x=1}^ {i} \frac{x+2}{4} , \ \ i \geq 0$$

Which can be expressed as:

$$a_i=\frac{(i+2)!}{2^{2i+1}} \ \ i\geq 0$$

But as you said this is just one of infinite possibilities :)

Comment: I'm going to say answered; only time will tell, but as far as I can see this is the best fit! However, anyone viewing this can feel free to post their ideas.

Very lovely function!

Comment: Actually, I realized, the next number should probably get smaller! But what you posted is still beautiful!

Comment: @JinnyEcckle it can also get into negative numbers?

Comment: I can't see how that would make sense given what it describes. Thank you for your time. I'd like to mark your answer as solved, if you can find what I'm referring to.

Comment: I'll mark as answered, as yours does fulfill what I first asked.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence defined by 
$$s_n := \frac{1}{24} \left(24 +(8a-17) n - 3(4a-5) n^2 + 4(a-1) n^3\right) \tag{$\star$}$$
Then 
$$s_0 = 1 \qquad s_1 = \frac34 \qquad s_2 = \frac34 \qquad s_3 = a$$
where $a$ is *any number you like*.

The formula $(\star)$ is an example of a [Lagrange (Interpolating) Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), which is what makes all "continue this sequence" questions utterly trivial: Given any finite number of terms, we can always find a polynomially-defined sequence that agrees with those terms as well as *whatever value(s) we choose to come next*.

---

Now, *probably*, the geometry of your figure doesn't correspond to a polynomially-defined sequence. (**Edit.** Actually, your new edit that "the numbers should shrink as the sequence goes on" guarantees that it doesn't.) But that's beside the point. Unless/until you show us your diagram and explain the phenomenon your sequence hopes to describe, one can concoct myriad interpolating functions that fit whatever numbers you provide; there simply is no objectively "correct" answer to a "continue this sequence" question like yours.

Comment: I will post it in a moment. Sorry about the lack of forethought on my part!

Comment: I posted a sketch. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called $I\left(n\right)$ that is equal to $\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{n}\right\rfloor$, which means when $n=1, I\left(n\right)=1$ and when $n>1,I\left(n\right)=0$. So, your sequence can be expressed as $\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{1-I\left(n\right)}$ or $\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{1-\left\lfloor\frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor}$.

Comment: Out of infinitely many possible continuations, you've picked the one that the question specifically rules out.